# Replace an image with a youtube video with css

Tags: html, css, image, replace, youtube

I'm using a template website. I would like to replace the existing image with a youtube video.  I know how to get the code from youtube to match the image dimensions, but I don't know what to change in the template.

Here's the code from the css...

```
.section-1 { background: url(../img/left-box-1.jpg) no-repeat center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; height: 600px; position: relative; }
```

And the corresponding section in the html...

```
<div class="col-md-8 section-1 nopadding" id="work">
                <div class="logo-1 wp1"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
<style>
.section-1 { background: url(../img/left-box-1.jpg) no-repeat center center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; height: 600px; position: relative; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-8 section-1 nopadding" id="work">
    <div class="logo-1 wp1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8dKLp2KB8u4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you, I did it.  I added the iframe to the div class "col-md-8 section-1" rather than to the "logo-1 wp1" and that did the trick! Then I went into the CSS and changed it from background: (url...) to background-color: black;

Comment: oh yeah, and I didn't use the script in the head. 
Thank you for your help!